# TreeMap not storing information

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a contact list that sorts by last names. When I try to store each contact into the TreeMap by using *lastName.put(last, array)*, everything works fine; however, the TreeMap does not store information after another while loop occurs. Can anyone help me with this? Forgive me if I'm using this forum incorrectly. I am very new to Java.

```
package Assignment;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class ContactList 
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        long storage = 99999;
        int choice;
        int secondChoice;
        boolean exit = true;
        int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Would you like to add a contact?"
                + " Type 1 for yes");
        choice = input.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            while(exit == true)
            { 
                TreeMap <String, List<String>> lastName = new TreeMap <String, List<String>>();
                List <String> array = new ArrayList <String>();
                System.out.println("Plese add first name");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add phone number");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add email address");
                array.add(input.next());
                System.out.println("Plese add last name");
                String last = input.next();
                lastName.put(last, array);


                System.out.println("This is what you just entered: " + lastName);


                System.out.println("\nWould you like to add another contact?"
                        + " Type 1 for yes - 2 for no");
                secondChoice = input.nextInt();
                if(secondChoice == 1)
                {
                    exit = true;
                    String hold = lastName.toString();
                    System.out.println(hold);
                }
                else
                {
                    for (Map.Entry product : lastName.entrySet())
                    {
                        System.out.println(product.getKey() + "   :   " + product.getValue());
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }  

}
```

}

Comment: You create a new `TreeMap` each time your `while` executes, so of course it doesn't contain the data you entered previously.

Comment: Please research the scope of variable in Java.

Comment: @Kyle make sure that you also make `exit = false` when the user selects `2 for no`

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments inline below, but the summary is that you are instantiating a new TreeMap each time you iterate through the while loop. Because of this, the map is going to lose all prior data each time you select that you want to add an additional contact. I've shown the TreeMap being provisioned just outside the loop, but you might want to move it up higher in the code for clarity.

*Additional points covered:*

1) **Close the scanner!** Leaving a scanner open can cause a memory leak, which no one wants.
2) You have no **exit condition** for the while loop. Currently selecting 2 just brings you back to the start of the program.
3) Type safety - Your Entry that you are examining in the for-each loop is a **raw-type.** I've updated the code to explicitly provision a type-specific Entry.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Moved scanner outside of the try-catch block so that it can be closed in the finally block.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            long storage = 99999;
            int choice;
            int secondChoice;
            boolean exit = true;
            int i = 0;

            System.out.println("Would you like to add a contact?" + " Type 1 for yes");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            // The TreeMap must go outside of the while loop, otherwise a new map is created each time.
            TreeMap<String, List<String>> lastName = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
            if (choice == 1) {

                // Should this be "while (exit == false)" and you initialize exit above to be false?
                while (exit == true) {
                    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
                    System.out.println("Plese add first name");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add phone number");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add email address");
                    array.add(input.next());
                    System.out.println("Plese add last name");
                    String last = input.next();
                    lastName.put(last, array);

                    // The format of this output is perhaps not what you want.
                    System.out.println("This is what you just entered: " + lastName);

                    System.out.println("\nWould you like to add another contact?" + " Type 1 for yes - 2 for no");
                    secondChoice = input.nextInt();
                    if (secondChoice == 1) {
                        exit = true;
                        String hold = lastName.toString();
                        System.out.println(hold);
                    }
                    else {

                        // Using "Map.Entry. etc..." isn't what you want here, and also isn't type-specific.
                        for (Entry<String, List<String>> product : lastName.entrySet()) {
                            System.out.println(product.getKey() + "   :   " + product.getValue());
                        }

                        // You should have an exit condition for the loop here. Currently it continues infinitely.
                        // exit = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using my program");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            input.close();
        }
    }
```